# Favicon using static url in Django

Tags: django, favicon

I'm linking the favicon to my site like so:

```
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}favicon.png" />
```

but it still doesn't show up. I've seen a lot of ways using a static uri, but I'd like to just keep the Django way of utilizing STATIC_URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You write STATTIC_URL with two "Ts"

```
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}favicon.png" />
```

But if you write "STATIC_URL" is possible that is not work.The favicon is very caching, access with private mode.

Comment: Sometimes I hate myself. I read it over 5-6 times and couldn't see it. Still doesn't work though, what do you mean by private mode?